How to query post requests on browser
I've been getting started with querying APIs, and I spent a while today frustrated with trying to do a POST request through my browser, the same way I was able to do GET requests. I folded and got Postman, but I wanted to know if there was a way I could do POST (and other non-GET requests) directly in browser.
I tried using the Mozilla console in Firefox but wasn't really sure where to go from there.

Call the fetch() function from the console:
let params = {x: 1, y: 2};
fetch('url', {method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify(params)}).then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text))

